# how to publish github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I've created a [branch named gh-pages](https://github.com/wholcomb/quickdiff/tree/gh-pages) and pushed it to github. The [username.github.io/projectname url](http://wholcomb.github.io/quickdiff/) is 404 however.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index.html in that branch looks like it is a symlink to the xhtml file.   Try just make it a copy instead of a symlink.

I tried this with one of my projects and confirmed that it will not work with a symlink but does work with the content in the `index.html` file.

Comment: Any ideas for what to do if you want to organize your code into a subdirectory on gh-pages? Suppose you want index.html to reside in that subdirectory and to have links and resources whose paths are relative to the subdirectory ... none of that at top level. But you want to symlink a top-level "index.html" that merely points to your subdirectory index.html.

Comment: @Mr. F I haven't tried this, but I think that you would be able to copy the index.html from the subdirectory and add a [base tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html) to the root index.html that points to the subdirectory.